# VS Code: change foreground color for files with problems in the file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having a hard time changing the foreground color for the 'problem files' in visual studio as shown below. The default color is black as shown in the snapshot below (look closer at the in 'index.js' file in the file explorer).

[image]

I will like to change the foreground color from black to any color so it the file can be visible when I use a darker theme. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From vscode **1.24** the colors for file explorer can be assigned separately from editor warnings:

```json
"list.errorForeground": "#f66",
"list.warningForeground": "#ff6",
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I got from the sonar community.

[Sonar Source Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/are-we-able-to-change-color-of-warnings/60107)

Add this to the settings.json file in your workspace.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#757575",  // Warnings inside the file
    "editorError.foreground": "#f66",       // Errors inside the file
    "list.warningForeground": "#757575",    // Warnings on the file name
    "list.errorForeground": "#f66",         // Errors on the file name
},
```