# VS Code - file explorer, how to change the text colour for files with errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the explorer sidebar, if the file has no errors then the colour is green, if the file has errors it turns red.  Is there a way to change the colours for when there are errors?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code: change foreground color for files with issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388212/vs-code-change-foreground-color-for-files-with-issues)

Comment: list.errorForeground in your colorCustomizations

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is to add the following setting into your settings.json:

```
    {
      "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "gitDecoration.conflictingResourceForeground": "#00AA00"
      }
    }
```

You can find more info about changing colors to certain elements (specifically git related elements) here in the offical VSCode documentaiton - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#git-colors